# Teleop based control of a custom vehicle

Tags: control, wifi, teleop, robot, keyboard-teleop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am making a ground vehicle which can be controlled over wifi signals using a keyboard. So rather than worrying about all the custom interfaces that i would have to create, i though of modifying the turtlebot teleop interface. Any help on how to procede would be great.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50845/teleop--based-control-of-a-custom-vehicle/) by [incognito](https://answers.ros.org/users/2784/incognito/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2012-12-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is my implementation of teleop for carlike robot. Instead of Twist (whish has 6 variables) I use simple Drive message containing only acceleration and steering angle. Hope it would be helpful somehow.

```
    #include "ros/ros.h"
#include "drive_base/Drive.h"
#include "sstream"
#include <termios.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


  #define KEYCODE_A 0x61
  #define KEYCODE_D 0x64
  #define KEYCODE_S 0x73
  #define KEYCODE_W 0x77
  
  class TeleopRoboCVKeyboard
  {
    private:
    drive_base::Drive cmd;
  
    ros::NodeHandle n_;
    ros::Publisher drive_pub_;
  
    public:
    void init()
    {

  
      //Clear out our cmd - these values are roundabout initials

      cmd.Acceleration = 0;
      cmd.Angle = 0;
  
      drive_pub_ = n_.advertise<drive_base::Drive>("command", 100);
  
      ros::NodeHandle n_private("~");
    }
  
    ~TeleopRoboCVKeyboard()   { }
    void keyboardLoop();
  };
  
  int kfd = 0;
  struct termios cooked, raw;
  
  void quit(int sig)
  {
    tcsetattr(kfd, TCSANOW, &cooked);
   exit(0);
  }
  
  int main(int argc, char** argv)
  {
    ros::init(argc, argv, "drive_cmd_publisher");
  
    TeleopRoboCVKeyboard tpk;
    tpk.init();
  
    signal(SIGINT,quit);
  
    tpk.keyboardLoop();
  
    return(0);
  }
  
  void TeleopRoboCVKeyboard::keyboardLoop()
  {
    char c;
   bool dirty=false;
  
    // get the console in raw mode
    tcgetattr(kfd, &cooked);
    memcpy(&raw, &cooked, sizeof(struct termios));
    raw.c_lflag &=~ (ICANON | ECHO);
    // Setting a new line, then end of file
    raw.c_cc[VEOL] = 1;
    raw.c_cc[VEOF] = 2;
    tcsetattr(kfd, TCSANOW, &raw);
  
    puts("Reading from keyboard");
    puts("---------------------------");
    puts("Use 'WS' to forward/back");
    puts("Use 'AD' to left/right");
  
    for(;;)
    {
      // get the next event from the keyboard
      if(read(kfd, &c, 1) < 0)
      {
        perror("read():");
        exit(-1);
      }
  
      switch(c)
      {
        // Walking
      case KEYCODE_W:
    puts("throttle");
        cmd.Acceleration = cmd.Acceleration + 10;
        dirty = true;
        break;
      case KEYCODE_S:
    puts("brake");
        cmd.Acceleration = cmd.Acceleration - 10;
        dirty = true;
        break;
      case KEYCODE_A:
    puts("turn left");
        cmd.Angle = cmd.Angle - 0.1;
        dirty = true;
        break;
      case KEYCODE_D:
    puts("turn right");
        cmd.Angle = cmd.Angle + 0.1;
        dirty = true;
        break; 
      }
  
  
      if (dirty == true)
      {
        drive_pub_.publish(cmd);
      }
  
  
    }
  }
```

---

Originally posted by [Peter Listov](https://answers.ros.org/users/3071/peter-listov/) with karma: 338 on 2012-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-12-20**:
You can choose to update only two of the 6 geometry_msgs/Twist parameters (the angular z for the "left and right" and the linear x for the "forward and back")

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The most convenient option would be to make it controllable via a [geometry_msgs/Twist](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Twist.html) message, with the topic name typically being "/cmd_vel". This way, you can use a lot of options for teleoperation that already follow this convention.

The fast and easy option I often use is the pr2_teleop package. By starting the keyboard teleop node you can quickly move a robot around:

```
rosrun pr2_teleop teleop_pr2_keyboard
```

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-12-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marlon Rocha](https://answers.ros.org/users/4496/marlon-rocha/) on 2013-04-10**:
I'm having problem with the drive.h

**Comment by [Quadrobo](https://answers.ros.org/users/8696/quadrobo/) on 2014-01-10**:
After going to the pr2_teleop wiki page, I wasn't able to download the package from the source page. Clicking on the link just shows a blank page.